# Incorrect data types for Postgres being passed in to query from Gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am trying to create an endpoint within my API for creating companies. Within the Company model I have a `[]string` for storing allow listed domains related to the emails users are allowed to use to sign up with.

The []string is initially mapped from a JSON POST request from an array and assigned the text[] type within Postgres.

```
AllowedDomains        []string `gorm:"type:text[];default:NULL" json:"allowedDomains" binding:"required"`
```

Full model with `Create()`

```
// Company is the primary struct type for companies
type Company struct {
    common.Base
    Name                  string   `gorm:"unique;default:not null" json:"name" binding:"required"`
    PrimaryContactName    string   `gorm:"unique;default:not null" json:"primaryContactName" binding:"required"`
    PrimaryContactEmail   string   `gorm:"unique;default:not null" json:"primaryContactEmail" binding:"required"`
    PrimaryContactPhone   string   `gorm:"unique;default:not null" json:"primaryContactPhone" binding:"required"`
    SecondaryContactName  string   `gorm:"unique;default:NULL" json:"secondaryContactName"`
    SecondaryContactEmail string   `gorm:"unique;default:NULL" json:"secondaryContactEmail"`
    SecondaryContactPhone string   `gorm:"unique;default:NULL" json:"secondaryContactPhone"`
    PrimaryDomain         string   `gorm:"unique;default:not null" json:"primaryDomain" binding:"required"`
    AllowedDomains        []string `gorm:"type:text[];default:NULL" json:"allowedDomains" binding:"required"`
    MFAEnabled            bool     `gorm:"not null" json:"mfaEnabled" binding:"required"`
    IsValidated           bool     `gorm:"not null"`
}

func (c *Company) Create() error {
    if result := common.Db.Create(c); result.Error != nil {
        log.Printf("Error creating company: %s", c.Name)
        return result.Error
    } else {
        log.Printf("Successfully created company: %s", c.Name)
        return nil
    }
}
```

In implementing this I am encountering two problems however.

First when `AllowedDomains` contains a single string the value is not being written to Postgres as an array, but rather as a single string.

```
api               | 2023/04/10 19:05:50 /go/src/api/company/model.go:25 ERROR: malformed array literal: "website.co.uk" (SQLSTATE 22P02)
api               | [2.006ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO "companies" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","name","primary_contact_name","primary_contact_email","primary_contact_phone","primary_domain","mfa_enabled","is_validated","secondary_contact_name","secondary_contact_email","secondary_contact_phone","allowed_domains") VALUES ('2023-04-10 19:05:50.551','2023-04-10 19:05:50.551',NULL,'Foo Company Ltd.','Foo','Bar','00000000000','website.com',true,false,'Foo2','Bar2','11111111111',('website.co.uk')) RETURNING "id","uuid","secondary_contact_name","secondary_contact_email","secondary_contact_phone","allowed_domains"
api               | [GIN] 2023/04/10 - 19:05:50 | 500 |    3.043083ms |      172.21.0.1 | POST     "/api/company/register"
api               | 2023/04/10 19:05:50 Error creating company: Foo Company Ltd.
api               | 2023/04/10 19:05:50 ERROR: malformed array literal: "website.co.uk" (SQLSTATE 22P02)
postgres          | 2023-04-10 19:06:35.523 UTC [19] ERROR:  column "allowed_domains" is of type text[] but expression is of type record at character 336
postgres          | 2023-04-10 19:06:35.523 UTC [19] HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
postgres          | 2023-04-10 19:06:35.523 UTC [19] STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "companies" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","name","primary_contact_name","primary_contact_email","primary_contact_phone","primary_domain","mfa_enabled","is_validated","secondary_contact_name","secondary_contact_email","secondary_contact_phone","allowed_domains") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,($14,$15)) RETURNING "id","uuid","secondary_contact_name","secondary_contact_email","secondary_contact_phone","allowed_domains"
```

Secondly, when the JSOn array contains > 1 values, the type being written to the database is of type `record` and not `text[]`

```
api               | 2023/04/10 19:06:35 /go/src/api/company/model.go:25 ERROR: column "allowed_domains" is of type text[] but expression is of type record (SQLSTATE 42804)
api               | [2.502ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO "companies" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","name","primary_contact_name","primary_contact_email","primary_contact_phone","primary_domain","mfa_enabled","is_validated","secondary_contact_name","secondary_contact_email","secondary_contact_phone","allowed_domains") VALUES ('2023-04-10 19:06:35.522','2023-04-10 19:06:35.522',NULL,'Foo Company Ltd.','Foo','Bar','00000000000','website.com',true,false,'Foo2','Bar2','11111111111',('website.co.uk','website.net')) RETURNING "id","uuid","secondary_contact_name","secondary_contact_email","secondary_contact_phone","allowed_domains"
api               | [GIN] 2023/04/10 - 19:06:35 | 500 |    3.256334ms |      172.21.0.1 | POST     "/api/company/register"
api               | 2023/04/10 19:06:35 Error creating company: Foo Company Ltd.
api               | 2023/04/10 19:06:35 ERROR: column "allowed_domains" is of type text[] but expression is of type record (SQLSTATE 42804)
```

When I set a breakpoint and analyse the `company` type after serialization however, it's clear that `AllowedDomains` is of the correct type.

[image]

Any ideas what I'm missing here or the best way to resolve this?

Comment: try using https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#StringArray instead of `[]string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment by mkopriva, the solution was to use the `pq` package as below.

```
package company

import (
    "github.com/lib/pq"
    "log"
)

// Company is the primary struct type for companies
type Company struct {
    ...
AllowedDomains        pq.StringArray `gorm:"type:text[];default:NULL" json:"allowedDomains" binding:"required"`
}

func (c *Company) Create() error {
    a := pq.StringArray{}
    if c.AllowedDomains != nil && len(c.AllowedDomains) > 0 {
        for _, v := range c.AllowedDomains {
            a = append(a, v)
        }
        c.AllowedDomains = a
    }
    if result := common.Db.Create(c); result.Error != nil {
        log.Printf("Error creating company: %s", c.Name)
        return result.Error
    } else {
        log.Printf("Successfully created company: %s", c.Name)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply use `pq.StringArray(c.AllowedDomains)` without an `O(n)` loop.